# Determine compression ratio for Windows compressed drive

Tags: windows-7, compression

Is there a Windows 7 native way to display the overall compression ratio on a Windows compressed drive?

As part of our disaster recovery process, we're copying some key system folders onto 2TB external hard drive, encrypted using TrueCrypt and copied using robocopy. The drive is compressed and I'd like to see what kind of compression ratio we're getting and whether it's actually worth the performance overhead.

I know that TreeSize can possibly do this (as mentioned in another post) but want a OS native way if possible.

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [compact command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact) is a native Windows command that displays or alters the compression state of files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the UI if available. Right-click on the relevant folder and note "Size", and "Size on disk". The calculated ratio of shown sizes is the compression ratio, minus the file allocation unit losses ratio.

Here are some screenshots courtesy of Biswapriyo's request.
The file is simple text Moby Dick from Project Guttenberg.

- File takes up more space than it's actual size due to allocation size, having a theoretical negative compression ratio of 0.997.

  [image: Normal file]
- File is compressed using the Windows built-in compacting mechanism, giving a compression ratio of 1.337 if calculating from uncompressed raw data, or 1.341 if calculating from uncompressed allocated space. Mind that are still losses from allocation alignment.

  [image: Compressed file]
- Compact command seems to agree with above calculations, albeit a little rougher on the floating point precision.

  [image: Compact command output]

Comment: Elaborate your answer. Add more details or some screenshots.

Comment: the first image is a normal file, which obviously must have its size smaller or equal to the allocated size. It's definitely not a compressed file with negative ratio